# How to know when UICollectionView has finished layout?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How is it possible to know when `UICollectionView` has finished laying out items?

Comment: can you please explain what u want to say in : when contentSize is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to determine existence of any animations performing in your collection view

```
NSArray animations = collectionView.layer.animationKeys;
if (animations == nil) {
    // no animations, layout is static
}
```

For example, you can try to set observer on this property.

Comment: Ok, you are write. The answer basically concerns animation transition. It is not the case for collection view layout